# List of unicode symbols and TeX equivalents

Tags: unicode

I am looking for a simple table with two columns: One column has unicode symbols (*not* images or anything else) (example: ∞) and another column has the TeX equivalent (example: \infty).

The table [here](http://www.johndcook.com/math_symbols.html) has exactly what I want, but I'm looking for a more complete list (the more symbols the better).

EDIT: What I'd like is unicode symbols which I can simply copy and paste into any text editor and it will be correctly rendered. In for example the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), if I try copying from the PDF the \pounds symbol into any text editor, I get instead "$".

EDIT 2: I am also a novice in programming, TeX, etc. What I want is to be able to copy paste such a table into Excel and be able to manipulate it. If I knew how to look at various source codes and extract and assemble the desired information into the desired table, I wouldn't bother posting here. I imagine I'm not the first and last person who would like to find this simple list. Perhaps no such list exists, in which case too bad for me. But I'm just asking.

Thank you.

Comment: Nope I've already looked at everything listed there. And none has what I want. Namely a simple table where one column there are the unicode symbols (NOT images or anything else). To repeat: the table at the website given is EXACTLY what I want, but I'd like a more extensive list. Thanks.

Comment: The comprehensive symbol list is probably as comprehensive as it gets. And it does **NOT** use images. It gives you symbols and commands together with some minimal information about what you need to do to use those commands, such as loading the appropriate package. You could take the source of that document and use it to create a two column table if you wanted to, perhaps excluding symbols only available through packages you prefer to avoid (if any).

Comment: Cite from Rebekah’s answer in [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14): “If you are using the package unicode-math, then besides using any Unicode character list, the list of all supported symbols (texdoc unimath-symbols) is very useful as it also lists which symbols are available in the various fonts.” And read also [Andrew Stacey’s answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120374/9237).

Comment: What is the limiting factor?  The *TeX side or the Unicode side?  Or should an entry exist only if there is already a Unicode *and* TeX command?  Should the table explain what package is needed to get the symbol?  (And of course some fonts are 'more complete' than others...)

Comment: Take a look at this list. It  may be what you want:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/189PohjhFHpPc-AXyHjDVLFAaOSZoUZ5MOYv_QrYSq3s/edit?usp=sharing